# Show All Employees Even If Zero or Null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I need to show a report weekly for sales of a specific item "Phone1".  When I currently run the report, if an employee does not sell that item it omits them from the report.  I want to show them even if no sales.

I have tried a few options including `(IsNull)` and `(IsNothing)`.  These still do not have the expected outcome.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Total.Value)), 0, Sum(Fields!New_and_Upgrade_Total.Value))
```

The result should show all employees withing the company even if they do not have a sale for that time frame.

```
EMP Name       |   Sales   |      Item      |
Employee 1     |     0     |     Phone1     |
Employee 1     |     5     |     Phone1     |
```

Comment: Are you hiding rows that don't have any sales? Are there any filters on the dataset preventing these rows from showing? What is the datasource (query) for the dataset?

Comment: No rows are hidden.  No filters have been added.  The query is to show .Value with no other filter there either.

Comment: Can you post your query which retrieves dats for you. Also are you passing parameter as some user and then trying to  return data based on selected user or something. Need more info like your query, returned result without any parameter or condition.

Comment: I guess I dont understand what is needed for help.  Im new to sql reporting.  have a very basic understanding of it.

Comment: You are most likely getting this data from an SQL Server database. We need to see the select statement that pulls this data from the database.

Comment: Your initial query, possibly a stored procedure, for your dataset, might be filtering out $0 sales, which would not return all employees. If you double click on your dataset name, it will show you the stored proc name or query embedded in the dataset properties. If you can paste the query into your post, it would benefit us in helping you instead of guessing and getting now where.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AHJbH98P